# Create a modal dialog popup on load which would appear only once a day

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, modal-dialog, popup, cookie

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', MyPopUp);

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
expires = "";
}
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function MyPopUp() {
             var options = { url: '/ict-services/Pages/the-rule.aspx', title: '10 Day Rule', width: 800, height:  600 };
var visited = readCookie('visited');
if (!visited || visited !== "true") {
        createCookie('visited', "true", 1);
              SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
          }
          _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyPopUp()");


</script>
```

I need a modal dialog which will load as shown in the code below.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', yourFunction);

      function yourFunction() {
     var options = { url: '/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx', title: 'Title,Description, and Icon', width: 640, height:  400 };
           SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
       }

       _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("yourFunction()");

  </script>
```

The script has to be written in such a way that the popup appears once a day. 
An example would be appreciated.

Ok...my update script including cookie that expires after I minute (this is for testing purposes - will change to 7 days on production)

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', MyPopUp);

 function createCookie(name,value,days) { var expires;
     if (days) {
         var date = new Date();
         date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
         expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
     }
     else { expires = ""; }
     document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; }

 function readCookie(name) {
     var nameEQ = name + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
         if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
     }
     return null; }

 function eraseCookie(name) {
     createCookie(name,"",-1); }

  function MyPopUp() {
         var options = { url: '/new.aspx', title: 'new title', width: 800, height:  600 }; 
    var visited = readCookie('visited'); if (!visited || visited !== "true") {
    createCookie('visited', "true", 1);
          SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); }
      }
         _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyPopUp()");


  </script>
```

Comment: you want to show the popup once a day for every user?

Comment: It is amazing Mike!!, I searched on *cookie once a day* and found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132173/show-div-once-a-day

Comment: @DannyEngelman If you know the existence, and functioning, of cookies it sure is easy to do that search. If you don't it is not so easy

Comment: Yes - I do need to show the popup once a day for every user

Answer (score 4):

Create a list like `ModalLogs` with following column `IsModalShownForToday`

Now find a item where `Created By` equals `current user` and `Created` equals `Today` and `IsModalShownForToday` is `true`. If you do not find any item by this filter, then show the modal and save a new item to `ModalLogs` list. Put the script in your master page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunction, 'SP.js');
         function yourFunction() {
             var options = { url: '/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx', title: 'Title, Description, and Icon', width: 640, height:  400 };
              if(modalLogExitsForToday()){
                      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                     }
          }

          _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("yourFunction()");

</script>
```

Right now I don't have the environment so that I am unable to give the code.

**Update:** As [garvon-77](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/13665/garvon-77) mentioned in comment that I he is quite new in scripting, so I am giving the script to do this. I am little bit busy today. So I could not refactor it. Anyway it will work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(modalLogExitsForToday, 'SP.js');

function modalLogExitsForToday() {

    var query = "<View><Query><Where><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"IsModalShownForToday\" /><Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Author\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\"><UserID Type=\"Integer\" /></Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today /></Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>";

    var data = {
        query: {
            __metadata: {
                'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'
            },
            ViewXml: query
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ModalLogs')/getitems",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.d.results.length == 0) {
                saveNewLog();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}

function saveNewLog() {
    var data = {
        __metadata: {
            'type': 'SP.Data.ModalLogsListItem'
        },
        IsModalShownForToday: true
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ModalLogs')/items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(data) {
            var options = {
                url: '/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx',
                title: 'Title, Description, and Icon',
                width: 640,
                height: 400
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("modalLogExitsForToday()");
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you _not_ want to use cookies for this?

Comment: Hey @Nit, I did not say that. I said it should work without cookie. I also mentioned that it could be bad solution. down vote was not expected.

Comment: localstorage in conjunction with a custom user profile property or a list like you say, so it does not matter if you use another device later. And the localstorage to only need to check once on the same device for property maybe.

Comment: Yes you are right @AndersAune. Same problem will be for cookie also. So I am updating my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Atish this will be a good start for me - I'm going to test this out but not till next week. If anyone has a cookie solution I would love to see this as well.
I do have questions - I know how to create lists and set in validation but I am new to scripting - this looks like I will need to create some script for this

"Now find a item where Created By equals current user and 
Created equals Today and IsModalShownForToday is true. If you do not find any item 
by this filter, then show the modal and save a new item to ModalLogs list."

Comment: cookie is not very good solution. will not work in other devices

Comment: Very grateful for your help. I am still very slow on the uptake as I get used to taking on small snippets of coding.
With the code above - I have created a list with a new column as outlined above...now with the additional code - where does it need to be placed? In the modal dialog page? I am not sure.

Comment: where you wish to show your modal? It is better to place it in your master page

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webpart with a personal property field and copy the script in a literal control. In the personal scope property will be stored current date. If the date is 'today', we can hide the literal, so there won't be model window. If the date is not 'today', we can assume that the user is login in first time today so we can enable the literal control and update personal field with current date.